# My React App wasn't displaying the components I created and I figured out why

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I Started a new project that displays my skills in React. To begin I started by creating a new file called **project13**. Secondly I created all of my html,css, and JavaScript files that I would need. to top it off I created all of my component files and even rendered my parent component to a div in my html file.At this point I feel satisfied that I have enough coding done to see this on a development server. I run the code down below in the terminal and press npm start to see a development server on **localhost:3000** that looks like nothing I have created.

```
npx create-react-app project13
cd project13
npm start
```

[image: Screenshot of port 3000]

I was so confused until I started doing research on creating a react app globally. I didn't realized that creating a react app had a build system that does most of tedious work for developers; it does this by creating the file, html, css, and having an src file you can add your components in. My mistake was firstly by creating a file, secondly creating my components, then lastly creating my react app. I will post down below what steps I took that lead to this problem with what steps I should taken instead down below. I hope this clears up some confusion earlier.

**Failed process:**

1. Creating a project13 folder
2. creating my html, css, JavaScript files.
3. creating all of my components.
4. `npx create-react-app project13`
5. `cd project13`
6. `npm start`

   **Successful process:**
7. `npx create-react-app project13`
8. `cd project13`
9. `npm start`
10. Start editing and creating my components in the src file.

Comment: Can you share screenshot

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information to offer a definite diagnosis, though my first instinct would be that you've already got another server running on port 3000. When you try to start the new project, perhaps the server is failing (leaving the existing server running) or it's using a different port. Honestly though, I'm just shooting in the dark. I think you'll need to refine your question. Unfortunately, this reads a bit like "I turn the key but my car won't start. What's wrong?"

Comment: I tried to put some more informative information in the screenshot. the development server was created successfully, but when I go to port 3000 it displays a completly different project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default create-react-app page after you run the commands above

What makes you think it's the wrong project?
What do you expect to see?

Comment: I expect to see the project that I'm working on which has completely different rendered elements. I think it has to do with one of the past projects where i created a react app globallly.

Comment: Why would you see the project you're working on, you have just created a brand new app?

Comment: @Paine8887 the only other thing I can think of is you have another create react app server running and localhost:3000 points to it

Comment: @JohnBehan thank you. I was doing the correct work, but I did the steps in an incorrect order which caused me confusion.